# How to get Attribute and Error Message on Specific Field YII2 in JSON

Tags: php, json, yii2, yii2-basic-app

Validation Rule :

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
      [['name', 'email', 'password'], 'required'],
      [['email'], 'unique'],
      [['password'],'string', 'min' => 6],
   ];
}
```

Scenario

```
public function signup() {
   if (!$this->validate(array('name')) {
      $register_errors['field'] = 'name';
      $register_errors['message'] = $this->getErrors('name');
   }

   if (!$this->validate(array('email')) {
      $register_errors['field'] = 'email';
      $register_errors['message'] = $this->getErrors('email');
   }

   if (!$this->validate(array('password')) {
      $register_errors['field'] = 'password';
      $register_errors['message'] = $this->getErrors('password');
   }
}
```

Return value

```
if (!$this->validate) {
   $register_errors['error'] = true;
   return json_encode($register_errors);
}
```

Result :
always return

```
{"field":["Email cannot be blank."],"message":[],"error":true}
```

How to properly return all field, error, and message of every field in JSON?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign the result always to the same index so you get only the last message
Try concat the message  usinng .=

```
public function signup() {
   if (!$this->validate(array('name')) {
      $register_errors['field'] = 'name';
      $register_errors['message'] = $this->getErrors('name');
   }

   if (!$this->validate(array('email')) {
      $register_errors['field'] = 'email';
      $register_errors['message'] .= $this->getErrors('email');
   }

   if (!$this->validate(array('password')) {
      $register_errors['field'] = 'password';
      $register_errors['message'] .= $this->getErrors('password');
   }
}
```

or assign the different message to different $register_errors['message'][]

```
public function signup() {
   if (!$this->validate(array('name')) {
      $register_errors['field'] = 'name';
      $register_errors['message'][] = $this->getErrors('name');
   }

   if (!$this->validate(array('email')) {
      $register_errors['field'] = 'email';
      $register_errors['message'][] = $this->getErrors('email');
   }

   if (!$this->validate(array('password')) {
      $register_errors['field'] = 'password';
      $register_errors['message'][] = $this->getErrors('password');
   }
}

var_dump(  $register_errors['message']);
```